# Narrowing index typed object of non-union value

Tags: typescript, types

I have an index typed object of any and I want to narrow it down.

It seems like union type can be narrowed down. Is it possible for non-union type also?

```js
const a:{ [k: string]: string | number } = {};
a.foo = 123; // type of a.foo is number, not string | number. 

const b:{ [k: string]: any } = {};
b.foo = 123; // type of b.foo is any, but I want number
```

What I actually try to achieve is compile time check of function arguments.

```js
const obj:{ [k: string]: (...arg: any[]) => string } = {};
obj.fn1 = (i: string, j: string) => i + j;
obj.fn2 = (k: number) => `${k}`;

obj.fn1('abc'); // should be error since second argument is missing
obj.fn2(false); // error, since type mismatch
```

Comment: As far as I know TS will not implicitly narrow down `any` types but you can do `if (typeof b.foo === 'number') { /* b.foo is number in the if block */ }` to narrow it down yourself.

Comment: In first example `a.foo` is `string | number`, not `number`. Typescript doesn't narrow anything after assignment https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLgN4wNoGsE2gJwJZgDmAulrgYTAD4xgCuAtgEYCmOMAvjALwxIcBuAFBwAdADMQIHjACMAJgDMAmAHpVMKAE8ADixghx8CVJh4I2KPiLVajVjlEwhQ7XpgAxU7zctDxyRAgA

Comment: Can't you just initialize object without explicit typing? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMBmYAjAFwwAUAlqdAE4VgDmANDItVHYwJSoB8MFGAGpWTbLgIAmUmQDWpMAFcAtvACmNHin4ADACTpZAXx1ijmTAkQA6AoTIByAIbxgDrgG5LSW2Elk8JwAbCDVPIA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Could you please check this playground? After assignment, referring a.foo is inferred correctly as a number.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLgN4wNoGsE2gJwJZgDmAulrgYTAD4xgCuAtgEYCmOMAvjALwxIcBuAFBwAdADMQIHjACMAJgDMwoaEiwmyNJmxR8RUvDABPTjP7CmEqTIXKhq8NBjjnvMZJACYAeh+1GVhxHdWwwABMZK09vPyNjIA

Comment: @AlekseyL. I'm creating a library so that explicit typing is not an option for now.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm not familiar with such behavior

Comment: Also not sure such behavior is desirable https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLgN4wNoGsE2gJwJZgDmAulrgYTAD4xgCuAtgEYCmOMAvjALwxIcBuAFBwAdADMQIHjACMAJgDMwoQxAATPOICeACjgBKFepABlEAxZQAFhQDqeGwDlG+iVKMwA9F5hSADhAANDA4dGBQeJYwbDggOEKJ4uHAkeAwapo6ujgsoDjqWABKefHqADzkRCFVlDT0zGwAfAZ8QjAdoaUF7tK8AOSSIP1CHEkpaWAwJuaWNvaO1i4Mug1YDaw4rUjtnaCQIAA2LKKHIISrjKJQIABieAAeLOq68gZGo0A